# Angularjs generic input directive with integrated validation

Tags: angularjs, validation, generics, directive

I have been trying to write a generic input directive with integrated validation. But I cant seem to get the validation  to fire (ng-show).

My guess is I don't really have a grasp on when the items are being evaluated by angular and added to the watch list but I am not sure.

My actual control is more complicated but have created a simplified version to illustrate the issue. 
The generated HTML (viewed with inspector) looks like it should work.
What am I missing? Here is the: [Plunker Validation Test](http://plnkr.co/edit/YMiZCP59SXhKGNcbt6Fe?p=preview)

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
<html ng-app="myApp">

  <head>
    <script data-require="angular.js@1.4.7" data-semver="1.4.7" src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular.js/1.4.7/angular.min.js"></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css" />
    <script src="script.js"></script>
  </head>

  <body>
    <form name='myForm'>
    <h1>Validation Test</h1>
    Name: <my-input uname='userName'></my-input><br>
    Phone: <my-input uname='phone'></my-input><br>
    </form>

   <script>
     var app = angular.module('myApp',[]);
     app.directive('myInput',function(){
       return {
         requires: '^form',
         replace:true,
         scope:{
           uname:'='
         },
         restrict: 'E',
         template: function(element,attr){
           return '<div><input class="reqclass" ng-model="' + attr.uname + '" name="' + attr.uname + '" ng-minlength="5"></input><span ng-show="myForm.' + attr.uname + '.$error.minlength">Too short!</span></div>'
         }
       };
     });
   </script>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Looks like myForm doesn't exist in your isolate scope.

Comment: OK I figured it out. Thanks Brett the comment was helpful.

Answer (score 0):

For anyone else with similar issue.
Thanks for comment, it led me to answer. See revised code below. 
Issue was access to form in isolated scope as well as attempting to use *form name rather than scope.form object in span*. 
NOTE the **require:['^form','?ngModel']** and in link: **scope.form = ctrls[0]** and revised **ng-show="form.' + attr.uname + '.$error.minlength"**
Plunker above has also been revised to reflect correction

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
<html ng-app="myApp">

  <head>
    <script data-require="angular.js@1.4.7" data-semver="1.4.7" src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular.js/1.4.7/angular.min.js"></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css" />
    <script src="script.js"></script>
  </head>

  <body>
    <form name='form'>
    <h1>Validation Test</h1>
    Name: <my-input uname='userName'></my-input><br>
    Not Directive: <div><input class="reqclass" name="city" ng-model="city" ng-minlength="5"/><span ng-show="form.city.$error.minlength">Too short!</span></div><br>
    Phone: <my-input uname='phone'></my-input><br>
    </form>

   <script>
     var app = angular.module('myApp',[]);
     app.directive('myInput',function(){
       return {
        require: ['^form', '?ngModel'],
         replace:false,
         scope:{
           uname:'='
         },
         restrict: 'E',
         template: function(element,attr){
           return '<div><input class="reqclass" name="' + attr.uname + '" ng-model="' + attr.uname + '" ng-minlength="5"/><span ng-show="form.' + attr.uname + '.$error.minlength">Too short!</span></div>'
         },
        link: function(scope, element, attrs, ctrls) {
          scope.form = ctrls[0];
          var ngModel = ctrls[1]; 
          }
       }

     });
   </script>
  </body>
</html>
```